# Use Gparted to remove windows partition and consolidate partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have deleted Windows and only run Ubuntu 18.04 at the moment. I looked at my partitions and there seem to be a whole bunch of different partitions including some related to Windows. I'd like to get to a state with as few partitions as I can, and have nothing relating to Windows, so that as much space as possible is free for my Ubuntu system in one partition.

I have looked at how to remove Windows partitions but mine has an ! next to it. I also can't follow some advice on other posts since I'm not sure which partitions I can change and which I can't. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, a disclaimer, as I can't *exactly* reproduce the steps to walk you through, this is just what I would try if I backed up all my important info first.

Here is a comparison of my partition table:

[image: my gparted]

I have a 500GB hard drive which is the `ext4` filesystem and the `fat32` EFI is used for the bootloader. So, you *could* delete the `ext4` fs associated with your Windows install (is that the one mounted at /media/ ?)

So it looks like you want to KEEP:

- fat32 EFI filesystem (that's the bootloader)
- ext4 linux storage filesystem ( presumably the 200GB partition ??, please double check)
- the linux-swap, which isn't *absolutely* necessary but helps free memory on low RAM systems

Everything else can be selected then *Partition > unmount* and *Partition > Delete*.
Once you have ~700GB of unallocated storage you can select `ext4` and then click *Partition > resize/move* and extend the drive to fill the unallocated storage. Finalize the procedures, clicking the green tick, and you should be set.

Comment: thanks so much. I'm completely new to this so I have no idea which partitions are which. I can tell you that  when I click on "Other Locations", I see "My Computer", which has 162 GB free space of 204.5 GB total, and "774 GB volume" which is dev/sda7 with 502.7 GB available. Does this answer any of the questions you asked me and should I proceed as you've stated?

Comment: Can you open "My Computer" and list out a few of the folders/files? and also do the same for "774 GB volume".

Comment: "Computer" has some of these folders: bin, boot, cd rom, dev, etc, home, lib.... "774 GB volume" has a folder labelled with my user name. Inside this folder there are a bunch of my documents and files, like things I've downloaded at some point I can't remember, and also the folders called documents, downloads, desktop, pictures, templates, videos, public....The stuff in this desktop folder for example is NOT what I'm actually seeing on my Ubuntu desktop though.

Comment: Okay, "Computer" is `/dev/sda3`, ie. your Ubuntu system, you will want to KEEP that. "774 GB volume" is `/dev/sda7` is your old Windows system, you will want to delete that. Please make sure there is nothing you want to keep before you delete as it will NOT be recoverable. Other than that you can proceed exactly as in the above post. Take it slowly, and if you have any issues, post in this chat room ( https://chat.stackexchange.com/account/2022711 ) and I will be more than happy to step you through.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked. Now I only have a fat32 efi partition and a single unallocated partition of 16 MiB before my single Ubuntu partition of almost 100 GB. I had to delete the linux-swap partition though since it was in the way of me extending my ubuntu partition to the unallocated 700 GB. Anyway, thanks and I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: No problem and well done!